# How to evaluate this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

How to evaluate $$ \int_{a}^{b} [x] \ dx \ \ +  \int_{a}^{b} [-x] \ dx \ ? $$

I know that

$[-x] = -[x]$ if $x$ is an integer, whereas $[-x] = -[x] - 1$ if $x$ is not an integer.

So is it about partitioning the interval $[a,b]$ with integers between $a$ and $b$, if any, as points of subdivision?

Comment: So $[x]+[-x]=-1$ "almost everywhere." The cases where $x$ is an integer basically don't matter. That said, Riemann integrals have difficulty with this sort of problem, you might need Lebesque integration.

Comment: I'm wrong about needing Lebesque, Riemann is just fine. Just make the intervals containing the integers smaller and smaller.

Comment: Is $\displaystyle{\large\left[\cdots\right]}$ the $\tt Floor$ function ?. If that's the case, it's better to use the notation $\displaystyle{\large\left\lfloor\cdots\right\rfloor}$ with $\displaystyle{\large\verb*\left\lfloor   \right\rfloor*}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the integral is linear we have

$$\int_{a}^{b} [x] \ dx \ \ +  \int_{a}^{b} [-x] \ dx =\int_a^b ([x] +[-x])\ dx.  $$

Now, $[x]+[-x]=-1$ except for a finite number of points (the integers belonging to the interval $(a,b).$) Thus the function $[x]+[-x]$ is Riemann integrable, since it has a finite number of discontinuities and its integral is the same as the integral of $-1$ because they differ only on a finite number of points. That is:

$$\int_a^b ([x] +[-x])\ dx=\int_a^b(-1)dx=a-b.  $$